# Cast Remote Display iOS error media::cast::AdaptiveCongestionControl::EstimatedAckTime

Tags: google-cast

Using Google Cast Remote Display API in an iOS game (NOT unity) and I see this in my crash logs (haven't been able to reproduce it on my end)

```
0x1002162b4 media::cast::AdaptiveCongestionControl::EstimatedAckTime(unsigned int, double) + 4296794804
0x1002163c8 media::cast::AdaptiveCongestionControl::EstimatedSendingTime(unsigned int, double) + 4296795080
```

This is in a crash:

```
com.google.cast.io EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000008
```

Any ideas? It does not seem to happen to a lot of users so far.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [forum](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=630), maybe it is due to `GCKDeviceManager` being deallocated during `postNotificationName:object:userInfo:`. Try to swizzle into `NSNotificationCenter`, and see that the `postNotificationName` dies, and that `GCKDeviceManager` was trying to remove its own subscriptions.

Also found this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=634) which states that:

> "Unless indicated otherwise, the caller should not release the delegating GCKDeviceManager object from within a delegate method." I found where the rule was not being adhered to. A change to delay setting our reference to the GCKDeviceManager makes the crash go away.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Will look into it right away and report back!